# How to hide/show button based on database value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Gridview and this code(down below) I want to show the button if the Status is open, otherwise the button should be invisible.

But this code, does not work. The button is always visible.

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (((GridView)sender).SelectedRow != null)
     {
         GridViewRow g = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
         string assign= GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
         btnassign.Visible = (assign == "open");
     }    
 }

<asp:Button Text="assign" ID="btnassign" Visible="false"
OnClick="btnassign_Click" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Have you debug what's inside `assign` variable? Maybe `assign` is always equals to `open`.

Comment: You have your code in the SELECTED INDEX CHANGED. That would mean to me that only when someone selects it will your code fire. `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the `AutoPostBack="true"` tag on your GridView.

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:GridView>`

Answer (score -1):

Better use the conditional operator

```
// ?: conditional operator.  
btnassign.Visible = (assign == "open") ? True : False;
```

Comment: How is this any different than the code he posted, other than being more verbose?

Comment: Also `True` and `False` are not values for a boolean in C#. `true` and `false` would be correct.